# local image is being returned as an integer - React Native

Tags: image, react-native, nsnumber

I'm trying to display a local image in my react native app.  The docs say the way that you do this is by doing something like

```
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />;
```

This works on its own, however I'm trying to pass this in as conditional logic if the api I'm getting data back from has a null url object.

```
<Image source={{uri: article.urlToImage || require("./awaiting.png")}}/>
```

When I do this I'm getting 'JSON value of '1' of type NSNumber cannot be converted to a valid URL'.

It seems to not like a combination of

```
<Image source={{uri: article.urlToImage }}/>
```

and

```
<Image source={require('./awaiting.png')} />
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help, the above solution didn't work but it let me on my way to this which does work

```
        <Image source={urlToImage ? { uri: urlToImage } : require("./awaiting.png")}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you cannot pass the result of `require()` as the URI in an object. Instead try:

`<Image source={urlToImage ? { uri: urlToImage } || require("./awaiting.png")}/>`

Answer (score -1):

I think A. Goodale might be correct. But if for some reason the lambda expression doesn't work then try separating into a function. I believe the lambda should work.